# Images overlapping header when hovered

Tags: css

In my photo gallery web application, I have a fixed position navigation bar at the top of the page. Below that, there are a series of images displayed. The issue I am having is that when hovering over one of the images at the top of the page, the image overlaps the header. The image below will make it clear what the issue is:

[image]

I have tried setting the images container and the individual images to `overflow: hidden;` but the same issue persists.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <ul class="container">
        <li class="item-list-container"><app-image-item
        *ngFor="let imageEl of images;"
        [image]="imageEl"
        (click)="onImageSelect(imageEl.id)"
        ></app-image-item>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.item-list-container {
    column-count: 4;
    column-gap: 1.1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 107px;

}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: set `z-index: 999;` property on header component

Comment: You should use the ngfor on li element of you want semantic html. If not, remove the ul entirely

Comment: Thanks for your help Norman this worked! @cloned thanks for this that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use z-index property in CSS.

z-index of the element you want to be above should be greater than the z-index of the element you want below it.